# Catching smtp exception in EmailMultiAlternatives django

Tags: python, django, email, smtplib

I am writing a management command where I will be sending emails to multiple recipients. I would like to make a log where I can tell if the mail is sent to a recipient successfully or  not. So far I am able to get this much code running

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from smtplib import SMTPException

    try:
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(data['subject'], data['text_content'], data['from_mail'], data['recipient_list'], bcc=data['bcc_address'])
        if data['html_content']:
            msg.attach_alternative(data['html_content'], "text/html")

        msg.send(fail_silently=False)

    except SMTPException as e:
        error_code,error_msg = e.smtp_code, e.smtp_error
        print error_code, error_msg
    '''except Exception as e:
        print e
        print "==========="
        print traceback.print_exc()'''
```

I am kind of stuck now. I deliberately put the wrong recipient emails in `data['recipient_list']`, but still I am not able to catch the error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. What is to correct way to catch smtp exception in django

Answer (score 0):

It won't work this way. SMTP server will send email regardless of whether such email exists or not. You may receive bounce email to your inbox later, but this is different case.

I'd say that should validate email address syntax and that's all you can do. You can also take benefit of send() return value which is number of emails sent.